# Python: Extract text from images with background

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I need to extract text from various screenshot, this is the code I'm using right now:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract
 

path_to_tesseract = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
image_path = r"screenshot_5850.jpg"
 

img = Image.open(image_path)
 
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
 
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="ita")
 
print(text)
```

My problem is that the result I'm getting is not accurate at all, and I think the problem is the background of my image: the text I'm interested in is always white with black border, but the background change in every screenshot and can be various colours. These are a couple of examples of the image I'm working with:

[image]

[image]

How can I improve my code? thank you all

Comment: I think you should convert image to black and white using OpenCV and then use pytesseract

Answer (score 0):

As @Stefano pointed out, some further image manipulation might be necessary.

Using `PIL`, you can simply call `img.convert("1")` to convert PIL Images to a black and white version.

See [this article.](https://holypython.com/python-pil-tutorial/how-to-convert-an-image-to-black-white-in-python-pil/)

#### Edit:

Since you pointed out that this approach doesn't work, I would try to use `PIL` to get it to be as black and white as possible. There's a million different [filters](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFilter.html) that you could apply with `PIL`.

If that doesn't work, the most extreme approach would be to iterate over all the pixels in the image, test if they are white, and if they aren't, set them to black. This would work since your text is always white, although any purely white areas of the background would be saved, so hopefully `pytesseract` can handle that.

```
# The extreme approach, keeping only white pixels
img = Image.open("c://path/to/file.jpg")
pixels = img.load() # create the pixel map

for i in range(img.size[0]):    # for every col:
    for j in range(img.size[1]):    # For every row
        # if the pixel isn't white, set it to black
        if pixels[i][j] != (255,255,255):
            pixels[i][j] = (0,0,0)
img.show()
```

Again, this is an extreme approach. You should play around with filters and your `pytesseract` settings (with which I'm unfamiliar) and try to get something easier to work first.

Comment: I've tried this method and it did not improve the result. Is there a way to keep only the text?

Comment: @DianaMele, I've edited with another solution, assuming none of the out-of-the-box editing options with PIL work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! When trying your code I'm getting this error at the line: `if pixels[i][j] != (255,255,255)` :
`TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2` . What am I doing wrong?